# Discord theme songs

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, voice

I want to give some of my friends theme songs and I have been able to do it using the code below

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(ctx, member, before, after):
        if member.name in theme_songs.keys():
            voice = await member.voice.channel.connect()
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=f"theme_songs/{theme_songs[member.name]}"))
```

The problem is the bot is activated every time something happens, i.e. muting, going live etc.
How could i make it so that it only looks for member joining?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add another `if` to check if they joined the channel

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(ctx, member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None:
        if member.name in theme_songs.keys():
            voice = await member.voice.channel.connect() 
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=f"theme_songs/{theme_songs[member.name]}"))
```